# Why is my command not remounting my partition as read-only?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, mount

Through the terminal, I used the `mount` command to find a disk partition that I wanted to remount as read-only. The specific one I am working with is `/dev/sdb2`.

I attempted to remount the disk as read-only with this command, expecting the disk to be remounted as read-only:

```
mount -o remount,r /dev/sdb2
```

There were no errors output.

However, when I entered the disk, I was able to create files on it, suggesting that the disk did not mount as read only.  Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the context of `-o`, or Mount Options, `r` is not equivalent to 'read-only'; in fact, it doesn't even exist.  You need to use `ro` instead - the full command becomes this: `mount -o remount,ro /dev/sdb2`

The only place `r` exists as an option for `mount` is as an argument, and not a mount option.

---

From the manpage on `mount`, I've pulled some informational sections here for you.  The `#`-preceeded comments are my own, and NOT from the manpage.

```
# 'mount' command arguments (NOT mount options, which are passed via `-o`!)

   -r, --read-only
          Mount the filesystem read-only. A synonym is -o ro.

   -o, --options opts
          Options are specified with a -o flag followed by a  comma  sepa‐
          rated string of options. For example:

                 mount LABEL=mydisk -o noatime,nouser


# FILESYSTEM INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS

   remount
          Attempt to remount an already-mounted filesystem.  This is  com‐
          monly  used  to  change  the mount flags for a filesystem, espe‐
          cially to make a  readonly  filesystem  writable.  It  does  not
          change device or mount point.

          The remount functionality follows the standard way how the mount
          command works with options from fstab. It means the  mount  com‐
          mand doesn't read fstab (or mtab) only when a device and dir are
          fully specified.

          mount -o remount,rw /dev/foo /dir

          After this call all old mount options are replaced and arbitrary
          stuff  from  fstab  is ignored, except the loop= option which is
          internally generated and maintained by the mount command.

          mount -o remount,rw  /dir

          After this call mount reads fstab (or  mtab)  and  merges  these
          options with options from command line ( -o ).

   ro     Mount the filesystem read-only.

   rw     Mount the filesystem read-write.
```

Comment: **mount -o remount,ro /dev/sdb2** does work indeed, checked it and proved it to myself. Thank you for your answer.